# Ruby on Rails mysql2 gem troubleshot

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I have created new ruby on rails project with mysql database.
I have run mysql server by running mysql.server start
When I try to run rake db:create, I got following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace
```

Anybody can solve this issue?
Please reachout me. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The salient details are that you need to update the **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH** to include **/usr/local/mysql/lib**. The easiest way of doing that is to add the following to your **~/.bashrc** file:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I went into a little more detail in a blog post here: http://www.bartbusschots.ie/blog/?p=2186